# SQL Server 2014 and DTS packages: The specified package could not be loaded from SQL server database

Tags: oracle, batch-file, ssis, ssms, sql-server-2014

I'm pretty young in BI and I'm stuck in here with some DTS packages, I have SQL server 2014 installed on 2 servers. In fact I have to execute a batch file from server1 which uses DTS packages to move data from a SQL server DB located in server2 to an Oracle db located in server1. I configured my packages locally and tried to run it with my BIDS when modifying the packages and it worked. What I really need is to just execute a batch file (with all parameters in it) to make the transfer.

The bat file is configured like this:

```
call myVariable.bat

"D:\...\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec" /ser SERVERNAME /U SQLUSER /P PSW /Conf "D:...\Config.dtsConfig" /sq "myDTSfile" 

call resetMyVariable.bat
```

The error I get is:

> The specified package could not be loaded from SQL server database. How can I add them to the db?

In SSMS 2014, I can't find anywhere an option to install or add dts packages to the db. Is there a way to do it with SQL Server 2014 or another solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Migrate your package to SSIS. Visit http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/coordinating-dts-ssis-migration
Or http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=169050